# fetch data from web-services iphone different ways?

Tags: iphone

Hi I am working on web-services getting data from web-service.

Data is in xml formate. i parsed data and display on my require Outlets. Every thing working great.

I want to work same parsing in different way. Is there any alternative way to fetch data from web service.  Or Xml parser is best among the other.

Help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use json parsing that is best way to hold data it always give you data in dictionary formate,and you can do XML parsing in 3 diff ways , may i know you using XPath query or just xml delegate method

Comment: i used xml delegate method for parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest TouchXML for parsing.

http://github.com/schwa/TouchXML

Comment: @Thanks Flash84x I do try TouchXML for xml Parsing.